# kubernetes cassandra operator error

Tags: docker, cassandra, kubernetes, kubectl, kubernetes-helm

I'm getting below error while creating cassandra operator for kubernetes.

```
# kubectl create -f example-cassandra-cluster.yaml 
error: unable to recognize "example-cassandra-cluster.yaml": no matches for cassandra.database.instaclustr.com/, Kind=CassandraCluster
```

`example-cassandra-cluster.yaml` is:

```
apiVersion: "cassandra.database.instaclustr.com/v1beta2"
kind: "CassandraCluster"
metadata:
name: "example-cassandra-cluster"
spec:
size: 3
version: "3.11"
pod:
resources:
  limits:
    memory: "512Mi"
```

Have anyone encountered this error before?

Answer (score 1):

The

```
apiVersion: "cassandra.database.instaclustr.com/v1beta2"
```

indicates that the CassandraCluster kind

```
kind: "CassandraCluster"
```

depends on a Custom Resource Definition.

That CRD has to be created in the cluster before instantiating its objects.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-kubernetes-api/extend-api-custom-resource-definitions/#create-a-customresourcedefinition

Comment: what version of kubernetes?

Comment: apiVersion: apiextensions.k8s.io/v1beta1        kind: CustomResourceDefinition       metadata:       name: cassandra.database.instaclustr.com       spec:       scope: Cluster names: plural: cassandra         singular: cassandra kind: CassandraCluster            shortNames: - ct          kubectl create -f resourcedefinition.yaml                                error: unable to recognize "resourcedefinition.yaml": no matches for /, Kind=CustomResourceDefinition

Comment: CRDs came into kubernetes at 1.7. prior to that the same concept was available with third party resources: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-kubernetes-api/extend-api-third-party-resource/

Comment: the version is 1.9

Comment: should probably make that a separate question. that error is usually a 1.5/1.6 error.

Comment: So how should we make the cassandra point to the previous version as it seems its having issue with 1.9.

Comment: I think there's a misunderstanding. There's no pointing cassandra at a previous version. If you are running a 1.9 cluster, then you will be able to run properly constructed CRDs. You should ask a separate question about the CRD resources, posting their full contents and provenance, and someone may be able to help you.

Comment: $ kubectl apply -f resourcedefinition.yaml =====
The CustomResourceDefinition "cassandra.database.instaclustr.com" is invalid: 
* metadata.name: Invalid value: "cassandra.database.instaclustr.com": must be spec.names.plural+"."+spec.group
* spec.group: Invalid value: "cassandra": should be a domain with at least one dot

Comment: apiVersion: apiextensions.k8s.io/v1beta1--------kind: CustomResourceDefinition

Comment: metadata:
  ------
  name: cassandra.database.instaclustr.com

Comment: spec:
  ----
  group: cassandra

Comment: version: v1beta2

Comment: scope: Cluster ------
  names:
   ----
    plural: cassandra-cluster
   
    singular: cassandra-clusters

Comment: kind: CassandraCluster
   -------
    shortNames:
    - ct

Comment: You're barking up the wrong tree. If you got the CRD and other config details from somewhere, then you should post those with a reference and someone familiar with them may be able to help. If you are just creating it yourself- you are a long way away from a solution. Longer than a StackOverflow answer. This is deep stuff. You will need to spend time reading and studying and testing. If the documentation is confusing, then you can ask questions, referencing specific places in the documentation. Good luck.

Comment: [https://github.com/arunkumar9050/cassandra-operator] ---this is the link of cassandra operator which iam trying to deploy

Comment: that looks very, very alpha. if the goal is get to a point of production automation and stability, and not just to fool around with cassandra- which one can do with a chart- it is going to take a very substantial and expensive effort.